# Node Script to console.log and return data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is a dummy script:

```
console.log('hello');
process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));
```

If I were to run `node index.js | jq .` this would cause a `parse error` because of the `console.log`. Is it possible to have a Node script that does console logs to the terminal, but then the data that is to be returned from the script (that can then be piped to other scripts) is separate? I want in the example above, `{foo: 'bar'}` to be piped only to `jq` but I still want to see the `hello` logged to terminal.

Comment: any chance u could write an interface for the log calls and overwrite the behavior im certain conditions

Answer (score 0):

According to [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args), the `console.log()` outputs to `stdout` (used as input by the piped `jq` command).

You can replace the `console.log` call by `console.error` since it outputs to `stderr` instead, and will not be read by the `jq` command. (unless you redirect stderr to stdout)